# When the second entry in the async function Redux-Toolkit createAsyncThunk I put it inside {} and I get the undefined value in the console

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

```js
export const addToBasket = createAsyncThunk(
  "newBasket/addToBasket",
  async (id, { cart }) => {
    return axios
      .get("https://run.mocky.io/v3/04fe3f95-0267-4ab4-a61b-a5f250151459")
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(cart); ---> undefined

        let data = res.data;
        data.map((item) => {
          if (item.id == id) {
            console.log(item);
            cart.push(item);
          }
        });
        return cart;
      });
  }
);
```

In the piece of code I posted, I did not expect the value of the second input of my async function to be undefined.

Answer (score 3):

The `createAsyncThunk` [payload creator function](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#payloadcreator) is passed two arguments, the first being the single argument value passed to the dispatched action, the second is the `thunkApi` object.

Refactor your code so you are passing `id` and `cart` in an object passed to the payload creator. ***Don't*** mutate the passed `cart` array, create new array references and update these. It's also a bit of an anti-pattern to mix `async/await` with Promise chains, so rewrite to `await` the GET request results and append the filtered response data by the specific `id` value.

```js
export const addToBasket = createAsyncThunk(
  "newBasket/addToBasket",
  async ({ cart = [], id }, thunkApi) => {
    try {
      const { data = [] } = await axios.get("....");
    
      return cart.concat(...data.filter(item => item.id === id));
    } catch(error) {
      return thunkApi.rejectWithValue(error);
    }
  }
);
```

Usage:

```js
try {
  const newCart = await dispatch(addToBasket({ id, cart })).unwrap();
  ...
} catch(error) {
  ...
}
```